# Tree of String Objects in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

I'm trying to translate a chess application that I had made in cpp, to java.
In my cpp version I had a structure which created a tree of strings.

Note, it was not a binary tree.
It was a vector of pointers, so from each node I had multiple subnodes stemming from it.
Does any one know how I could create a similar class in java?

Comment: You're probly getting down voted because you were too vague.  It might help to post some of your cpp code.

Comment: How many kids does your each node has ???

Comment: @UncleIroh I downvoted because this is a trivial problem that the poster doesn't show any signs of having tried to solve.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ChessObject() {
   private String description;

   private List<ChessObject> subChessObjects;

}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's a great answer given the question.  You should re-read it mate.

Comment: I already did read it.  Which is why I flagged it as 'low-quality'.  The comment was auto-generated.

Comment: Well I'm more than happy to add clarification as more information becomes available see my comment above, but for just the bare basics of a structure one could use to create a tree of String nodes I believe my answer is adequate.

Comment: I don't see any reason to flag this as "not an answer".